# How do I display the raw value of a CCK field securely?

Tags: 6, theming, entities

I have a CCK field that I can print out by doing:

```
print $node->field_cck[0]['value'];
```

Are there any security concerns with doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes! Lots of security concerns. You'll want to use `check_plain()`, `check_markup()` or one of the other functions to output that securely.

Check out [Writing Secure Code](http://drupal.org/writing-secure-code) for more information.

Comment: In most cases you can also use $node->field_cck[0]['safe'];